# a href tel and standard browsers

Tags: php, jquery, html, anchor, tel

I have a project that requires `<a href="tel:123456">` over the phone number (123456 is not the number) however this will cause an issue for everything except mobile browsers by being unable to interpret the `tel:` bit.

I have tried to use jQuery to add the href attr when a browser width is <1000px but this is a very unreliable method (tablets also have a limited resolution).

Any ideas on how to overcome this would be greatly appreciated. I am using PHP, jQuery and JavaScript.

Comment: One more way to detect mobile device.. http://ajaxhistory.com/other-scripts/detect-mobile-device-phone-with-javascript/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Detect with PHP if its a mobile agent:
http://www.000webhost.com/forum/scripts-code-snippets/27404-php-extremely-simple-way-check-if-mobile-browser.html

```
   <?php
        if(strstr(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), 'mobile') || strstr(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), 'android')) {
           echo '<a href="tel:123456">';
        }else{
           echo 'You are not in a mobile';
        }
   ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using PHP I can recommend the [php-mobile-detect](http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/) class. You can cater to individual devices/OS'es/browsers, or simply use `isMobile()` or `isTablet()` as a catch-all.

I usually do something like this:

```
include './includes/Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;

if ( $detect->isMobile() or $detect->isTablet() ){
    $phone='<a href="tel:+12345678910">1-234-567-8910</a>';
} else {
    $phone='1-234-567-8910';
}
```

Then I just `<?php echo $phone`;?> wherever I need it and it works a treat! And by using PHP instead of javascript it means the detection is done server-side, so the end user has less to download (like jQuery and extra scripts).

The library of devices gets updated fairly often, so it's worth checking the [GitHub page](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect/tags) every so often.

Answer (score -1):

Try this below one :

**Syntex : callto**

```
<a href="callto://9566603286">9566603286</a>

 <?php
    if(strstr(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), 'mobile') || strstr(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), 'android')) {
       echo '<a href="callto://9566603286">9566603286</a>';
    }else{
       echo 'You are not in a mobile';
    }
 ?>
```