# Is there a way to tell if an end user will be able to handle <a href="tel:###"> links?

Tags: html, uri, url-scheme

So if you want to link to a phone number you would do something like

```
<a href="tel:18005555555">Click to Call</a>
```

This is used commonly on mobile websites and is gaining traction on desktop sites as well (largely thanks to Skype I think.)  However some computers/devices aren't able to support it.  Is there a way to tell if a user is able to handle tel: links?

Solution can be either server side or client side but I would imagine it would need to be client side.

Comment: I find this very amusing: I was investigating *exactly* this issue (and for `geo:` links) just one hour ago.

Comment: One "discussion" (one-sided!) on the topic that I found was http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?610038-Detecting-Browser-Support-For-Speciic-URI-Schemes-(geo-tel-etc-). The technique there doesn't work for me in Chrome on Ubuntu; Chrome tries to pass it to `xdg-open` when clicked and the XMLHttpRequest doesn't fail.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan - Ya that solution seems buggy at best, this is unfortunately a tough issue to Google

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - that seems to be for <input type="tel"> not <a href="tel:#">

Comment: I'd suggest closing this as a duplicate of [a href tel and standard browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456387/a-href-tel-and-standard-browsers), but I couldn't bear to do that to a good question in favour of a question which heads in the wrong direction, with answers purely to do with detecting mobile browsers... fortunately, the question there can be construed as asking how to detect mobile browsers rather than `tel:` URI scheme support, so I am happy to not mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan - Appreciated, that restraint is missing and needed in a big way these days on StackOverflow in my opinion.  I saw that one too in the related questions list and actually considered downvoting it and/or doing a massive edit of it since as you say they end up going in a completely bizarre direction that doesn't actually answer the question at all.

Comment: As for [Check if <a href=“tel:5555555”> is supported](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16810356/check-if-a-href-tel5555555-is-supported)... well, I guess we have a duplicate there. And no useful answer. :-(

Comment: @AndrewG.Johnson: I'm also biased by really wanting a good answer myself!

Comment: Tried the solution in [How to launch apps (facebook/twitter/etc) from mobile browser but fall back to hyperlink if the app isn't installed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13675901), didn't work at all in Firefox, so it didn't satisfy me at all.

Comment: @Sergio: sorry, but that's absolutely no use. We're talking browser, not native. People also forget that it's not just mobile browsers that can support `tel:`, `geo:`, etc. Other environments can, too.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan, true. Removed.

Comment: See this link to get better answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164004/how-to-mark-up-phone-numbers

Comment: @zeenfaiz: that doesn't offer any solution to the question here.

Comment: How the Windows OS knows which application to trigger for which _protocol_ is by checking for the entry in the registry HKLM. It is called the URI Scheme as mentioned by the [Microsoft MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx). But client side scripting in web development do not allow you to read registry entries for security reasons, Therefore your closest work around would be to check for the user's [browser user agent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_useragent.asp) to guess which device is being used..(unless [Java Web](https://jna.java.net/) is allowed)

Comment: Did you check the answers in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872090/how-to-check-if-a-custom-protocol-supported this is basically the generalized version of your question.

Answer (score 2):

[DeviceAtlas](https://deviceatlas.com/) and [Wurfl](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) can get you some of this information, but as many have pointed out, there’s really no truly reliable way to detect a device’s ability to make a call. After all, someone might be on desktop, but capable of making a call from it based on the software they have installed (or even their OS capabilities).

In the interest of providing the best experience, you should include `tel:` links. That will give everyone the opportunity to dial the number if they can handle it. You could use CSS to make it look less link-like to reduce potential confusion for non `tel:` supporting browsers/OSes. Users who want to call the number will select it or touch it anyway (in hopes of copying the number) and will either activate the link (in touch scenarios) or see the hand (in mousing scenarios), helping them more quickly achieve their goal.

As a bit of an aside, setting `white-space: nowrap` on `tel:` links is always a good idea too :-) That will keep numbers on a single line so the hyphens don’t allow it to break.

```
a[href^=tel:] { white-space: nowrap; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, but if you enter the below header information

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=yes">
```

You will be able to enter phone numbers without the tel: prefix (or even an anchor) and the browser will auto-convert them to clickable phone links.

I think this may be more reliable than feature or agent detection.

Comment: I don't really like this way of doing it... it's not proper data, then—and how widely is it supported? For myself, I also want it for `geo:` links, so this isn't a general solution. Thanks for the thought, though; it may well be useful for some situations.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm coming along almost 10 years later, but I looked into this issue for tailoring the UI in one of my web apps and ultimately the answer that I settled on was a toggle option on the main user menu:

```
✔ This device is a phone
```

When the user toggles this setting on or off, the result is stored in the browser's `window.localStorage`, so that it can be remembered for later sessions.

The exact wording will depend on your application and why you need to know, but at the end of the day the user *knows* if their device has the ability to make calls, whereas without asking them, the best we can do is *guess*.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can tell there doesn't seem to be a good reliable way of doing this. It depends on what software is installed besides the browser and as such I don't think it would be exposed to a webpage (otherwise you can use it to check if the user has certain software installed, especially with application specific links like itunes or visual studio).

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments firefox does try to navigate and will instead show an error page show the below solution won't work for firefox.

An alternative to this is to simply handle someone clicking on it and it not working decently. Testing with chrome it seems the browser simply does nothing if the protocol is not recognized so you could just add an onclick that takes the part after `tel:` and transform `click to call` into the actual number. So clicking on it shows the number if they don't have anything installed which is perhaps a decent compromise?

Comment: Firefox at least (stock, desktop) will unload your page, showing an error page as it cannot understand `tel:` links. Chrome also may be able to handle it and you cannot tell whether it has handled it or not. This approach is thus fundamentally unworkable.

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know detecting what capabilities / applications a user has can be tricky for security reasons, but you can rule some things out and go from there.

You could try see of its a mobile browser which can handle the link, and then if not, see if the other device is capable of using a telephone number, e.g. Skype, and again if not, just display a normal number.

this combines answers from these questions a [href tel and standard browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456387/a-href-tel-and-standard-browsers) and [Javascript to detect Skype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358397/javascript-to-detect-skype)

```
<div>
<?php if(strstr(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), 'mobile') || strstr(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), 'android')) { echo '<div id="tel"><a href="tel:123456">123456</a></div>'; }else{?>
    <script>
            function skype (failureFunction) {
                var $ = jQuery;

                if ($.browser.safari || $.browser.opera) {
                    return true;
                } else if ($.browser.msie) {
                    try {
                        if (new ActiveXObject("Skype.Detection")) return true;
                    } catch(e) { }
                } else {
                    if (typeof(navigator.mimeTypes["application/x-skype"]) == "object") {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                $('a[href^="skype:"]').click(function() {
                    failureFunction();
                    return false;
                });
                return false;
            }

        jQuery(function($) {
            if (skype()) {
                $('div#tel').html("<a href='skype:123456'>123456</a>");
            } else {    
                $('div#tel').html("<p>123456</p>");
            };
        });
    </script>
    <div id="tel"></div>
    <?}?>
```

I hope its a step in the right direction for yer

Answer (score -3):

A client side implementation could be realised using the [BrowserDetect](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html) script and filter the user's browser properties with this list: [Can i use: URI](http://caniuse.com/#search=uri)

```
var browser = BrowserDetect.browser;
var browserVersion = parseInt(BrowserDetect.version);
var supportsURI = true;

if((browser == 'Firefox' && browserVersion < 2) || (browser == 'Explorer' && browserVersion < 8) || (...)) {
    supportsURI = false;
}
```

(not tested)

If the browser doesn't support URI-Schemes you can trigger the link and show a lightbox containing the required data (e.g. the phone number).

Comment: Would that it were that easy. This is a case where the same browser may or may not support the `tel:` scheme, specifically.